# Unable to Locate Usage of Local Scope Method in Laravel Eloquent Model via IDE

Tags: php, laravel

I've defined a local scope method in a Laravel Eloquent model,
but my IDE doesn't seem to recognize its usage locations.

When I click on the local scope method within the defined Eloquent model,
the IDE fails to show where this scope is actually being used.

Is there a way to enable the IDE to track and display the usage of these local scope methods in Laravel?
Any suggestions or tools that can assist with this would be greatly appreciated.

I'm working with Laravel Eloquent and have a custom local scope defined in my model. Here is a generalized version of the code:

php(7.1), laravel(5.6)

```
public function scopeCustomScope($query): Builder
{
    return $query->where('column_name', constant_value);
}

public function someMethod()
{
  
    return MyModel::query()->customScope()->get();
  
}
```

Plugin use failed.
PHPDoc annotations only find the model and do not accurately find the scope method.